# one SCDF source, 2 processors but only 1 processes each item

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

My use case is a variation on this:

[Create Stream with one source, two parallel processors and one sink in Spring Cloud Data Flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45125015/create-stream-with-one-source-two-parallel-processors-and-one-sink-in-spring-cl)

In the example, 1 source emits an item to rabbitmq and *both* processors get it.

I want the opposite.  I want the source to emit items to rabbitmq but only 1 processor handles each item.

Lets pretend I have:

1 source named source
2 processors named processor1 and processor2

So source emits: A, B, C to rabbitmq

RabbitMQ will emit A

Whichever processor gets A first will process it - lets say processor1 is the lucky one and handles A.

Then RabbitMQ will emit B

Since processor1 is busy with A and processor2 is idle processor2 handles B

RabbitMQ will emits C

processor1 finished with A and is idle so processor1 handles C

The Spring Cloud Data Flow graph I came up with is:

[image]

processorA is the one on top, processorB is the lower one

When I deploy this and run it, source emits A, B and C then *both* processor1 and processor2 receive A, B and then C

I'm confused if the behavior I want is something I can make happen in Spring Cloud Data Flow OR if there is a RabbitMQ setting for this as implied by the answer that says message removal

"is what is happening when you set the auto-acknowledge flag. In that way, the message is acknowledged as soon as it's consumed - so gone from the queue."

If that's the case, can I set it in my Spring Cloud Data Flow source OR is it a RabbitMQ setting or is it something else entirely

UPDATE:

I have added

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.group=consumerGroup
```

to the application.properties file of my processor.

Unfortunately, both processors are receiving the exact same data.

Do I need to add a similar entry to the application.properties of my source?

Do I need to change the annotation on the processor?  Currently, it is:

```
@Transformer(inputChannel = Processor.INPUT, outputChannel = Processor.OUTPUT)
```

Do I need to modify the annotation on the source in any fashion?  Currently, it is:

```
@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = Source.OUTPUT, poller = 
     @Poller(fixedDelay = "1000", maxMessagesPerPoll = "1"))
```

Does the inclusion of @Poller change this in any fashion?

UPDATE:

Is the property named spring.cloud.stream.instanceCount?

Comment: See the [SCDF Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.7.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_deployment_properties) and [Passing Instance Count](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.7.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_passing_instance_count).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For stream apps, you need to set the ...consumer.group property so they are both in the same group and compete for messages.

But that should happen automatically with SCDF.

Comment: Is it available for any SCDF source app or only the one named 'rabbit'.

Comment: It goes on the processor consumer, not the source.

Comment: Understood.  Can you confirm the source does not have to be the rabbit source app?

Comment: The source is irrelevant. Take a look at the exchanges and queues that are bound to them.

Comment: Got it.  Will do 1st thing in the morning.  Thank you very much.

Comment: I have made the changes and its not working.  I've updated the original question with my findings

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question; I assumed processor1 and processor2 are 2 instances of the same processor. That's why I said `"But that should happen automatically with SCDF"` (using a group name). But it sounds like that's not what you mean. If you mean alternate between 2 different processors, I don't think what you are trying to do is possible with SCDF - at least with normal topolgy. I think you will need to use the rabbit sink and then use rabbit sources for the input to your two processors.

Comment: yes, processor1 and processor2 are 2 instances of the same processor.  i want the output coming out of the source to be picked up by either one processor or the other BUT NEVER both.  is this a use case for the rabbit sink and rabbit source?

Comment: So just deploy the stream as `source | processor | sink` and set the processor instance count to 2 and it will just work - SCDF will automatically put the 2 processors in the same group.

Comment: made an update, want to confirm i got the right property